# puedo pasar datos de un json a otro?

Tags: ajax, json, nodejs, mongodb

estoy tratando de enviar algunos datos al front pero no quiero que vayan mas de la cuenta, esttoy usando nodejs y mongodb por lo querecibo un json de datos de mongo algo asi

```
 usuarios.find({rol : programadores })
    .then(doc => {
       const documento = {usuario, amigos, lenguajes, aportes}=doc

       res.end(documento)
    })
```

pero si hago un `console.log()` de documento veo que este contiene campos como la contraseña, usuario etc y desde el ajax en javascript modificando la parte que recibe y escribe en pantalla los datos puedo sacar la contraseña usuario etc

intenté iterar la respuesta de mongodb y así ir añadiendo algo así

```
    Users.find({ied:res.locals.user.ied, rol: req.params.id})
    .then(resDoc => {
        let documento = {};
        resDoc.forEach(doc =>{
        documento += {usuario: doc.usuario, rol: doc.amigos, contraseña: doc.lenguajes, telefono: doc.aportes}
    })
    console.log(documento)
        res.end(documento)
    })
```

y obtengo en consola [objet, objet]

alguien sabe como ayudarme a hacer que solo se envien los datos que quiero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres sacar sólo unos pocos campos de `document`, puedes usar `map` sobre el *array* de resultados.

```
const { ied } = res.locals.user;
const { id } = req.params;
Users.find({ ied, rol: id })
     .then(res => {
        // Mapea cada documento
        // con los campos que quieras sacar de él
        const docs = res.map(doc => ({
          usuario: doc.usuario,
          rol: doc.rol,
          contraseña: doc.contraseña,
          // ...
        }));

        res.end(docs);
     });
```

Dejo [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) la documención del método `map`.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchaas gracias me sirvio tu respuesta, de verdad gracias lo necesitaba enserio